# gitosis interferes with hadoop

Tags: git, hadoop, interference

Never thought I'd write a title like that, but it's true

I have gitosis and hadoop installed.

```
> sudo /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
  Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': 
  root@localhost's password: 
  localhost: DEBUG:gitosis.serve.main:Got command 'cd /usr/lib/hadoop ; 
             /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /etc/hadoop/conf 
             start datanode'
  localhost: ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Unknown command denied
```

WTF?!
Why are these commands suddenly being passed to gitosis?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, /root/.ssh/authorized_keys had the following line generated by gitosis:

```
### autogenerated by gitosis, DO NOT EDIT
command="gitosis-serve root@...",no-port-forwarding,...
```

Removed gitosis, removed this line, everything works

Comment: which is why you setup gitosis under it's own git user. :)